How does this AM modulator work
Attached is a basic AM modulator circuit using an ideal symmetrical transformer. I have left out the bottom section connected to simplify the process. As expected, the output will be a negative envelope according to simulation results. This is my attempt to explain:
From the positive half cycle of V3 (sinewave message signal), it causes the current to flow through winding Tr2. At the same time, the same current is reflected across winding T1. The negative half cycle of V3 won't matter because the diode blocks the current in this direction. But how does V4 (the carrier signal) flows in a way that follow the shape of the message signal. What is the role of the ground here?

Your V4 is used to lock/unlock the diodes.
The center point of the transformer must be the ground to fix "potentials".
The amplitude must be enough to do so.
To be clear, you can make the study of 2 cases.
My generator V3 (carrier) is rectangular form (enough amplitude).
Try just following the current of the diodes.
1- The resistor R2 is very low (1 Ohm).

When D1 is off (D2 is ON), vo =  4 - 0.7 V.
When D2 is off (D1 is ON), vo = -4 + 0.7 V.
Voltage output is "reported" to point vo1 or vo2, where diode is off
(transformer effect with "correct" polarity).
2- The resistor R2 is 50 Ohm.
The behavior is the same, just a little complicated.

3- The resistor R2 is 50 Ohm.
The generator V2 is a sinusoidal wave.

4- Here is the Fourier content of this behavior.
You can see the modulation and "harmonics" behavior.


That circuit can work better if you switch the two generator positions. If so, the modulation generator benefits from a D.C. offset (if you want "linear" AM modulation). The transformer now need not pass low-frequency (1kHz in this example), but it passes the higher-frequency (100kHz).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
V1 in the circuit above has a D.C. offset equal to the peak amplitude of the sine wave signal... for example a 400mV peak-to-peak sinusoid of 1kHz riding on top of a 200mV D.C. voltage.
V2 has enough amplitude to drive the diodes in switching fashion. Amplitude is not so high that diode peak current is excessive (10mA max. perhaps for 1N4148).
These diodes act as switches...when V2 reaches a +ve peak, the diodes effectively short-out Vout to GND. When V2 goes negative, diodes are open-circuit and V1 propagates to Vout unmolested.
Vout will still have that DC offset: with AC coupling that rejects low frequency 1kHz and below, but passes 100kHz, recognizable AM modulation results.

This is  a half-balanced modulator. A superior result uses 4-diode ring and two trifilar transformers (instead of the one shown). The fully-balanced modulator has fewer undesired output frequencies than the one shown.
The fully-balanced version is available as a complete unit. You should drive its "I.F. port" with the low-frequency signal, and one of the "R.F. ports" with the local oscillator signal. Ensure that you choose one of these modules that allows I.F. frequencies all the way to D.C.
